# Calculating a First In First Out inventory with expiration in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

Say that you are the owner of a factory that makes gizmos, and you are trying to plan your inventory for future years. You have a forecast of sales (that ranges between 1 and 5 gizmos per year). And your factory produces 4 gizmos every year.

We can take the cumulative sum of the difference between gizmos produced and gizmos sold in order to find the inventory in any year:

```
    # --- Initialize df --- 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'year':list(range(2010,2020,1)),
                       'gizmos_made':[4]*10,
                       'gizmos_sold':[2,3,2,1,5,2,2,3,4,2]})
    df = df.set_index('year')

    # --- Calculate yearly inventory changes --- 
    df['gizmo_inventory'] = (df['gizmos_made'] - df['gizmos_sold']).cumsum()

    df
```

[image]

However, lets say that the gizmos actually expire after two years (that is, a gizmo produced in 2018 will expire in 2020). The customer does not care if they receive a gizmo that is brand-new or about to expire, but we are always trying to get the oldest gizmos made out of the warehouse first.

What is an efficient (preferably vectorized or mapped) method of doing this?

I have a very long-winded implementation that creates an `inventory` column filled with lists of years (one for each gizmo) and then pulls out the oldest gizmos from each list in a loop. This is not scalable though, as in reality, I need to deploy this in a case with millions of gizmos.

Comment: I think your example is too simplistic. Presumably you have either a gizmo creation date or a gizmo expiry date? Sort the df first by gizmo identifier (name/product code/whatever) and have the secondary sort condition be the date. When you want a gizmo, sort the df, `groupby(gizmo_identifier)` and take take `first()`. Do you have such fields? What you have shown is too high-level to differentiate between gizmos of the same type

Comment: @roganjosh, In reality this isn't about a product at all, it's for a webapp that helps entities plan for a renewable-energy policy. The policy provides entities with one 'credit' for each unit of renewable-energy purchased. Entities are required to hand over a number of credits every year. Credits expire after two years. Because some entities will require millions of credits, and this will run on a small webserver, avoiding a long-df is preferable.

Comment: My continued use of "gizmo" implies that I don't really care what it is, because the principle should be the same. That info doesn't help me understand the problem any better. Please address the points I made in the first question, or I think your question doesn't actually encapsulate the real issue here

Comment: Because now I wonder where you're storing gizmo data. Probably MySQL/Postgres? In that case, the whole issue of a large DF would be avoided by pushing the filtering down into SQL

Comment: There is no gizmo data. Annual production/sales totals are the most discrete representation we have. There is no differentiation between gizmos besides the year they were created (not even the date). This is all in pandas.

Comment: If that is the lowest level of granularity then why don't you just pick credits that were awarded last year? A simple filter on the data by the year it was created, and whether it was assigned or not. I can't see anything further you think you could be doing?

Comment: It also can't all be in some dataframe on a web server. The entire dataset can't be sitting in memory, and memory alone. A single server crash would wipe out millions of datapoints. You're getting that data from some kind of disk storage, whether a CSV or a database. Surely?

Comment: The core of this question is assessing how to work with a df where rows are *aggregations* (here, they are years), there is no underlying df with one row per gizmo/credit.

Comment: "Because some entities will require millions of credits, and this will run on a small webserver, avoiding a long-df is preferable". If you're only dealing with _aggregations by year_ then how could you possibly have a long df unless you'd been selling credits for millions of years? This all seems contradictory. It seems I can't follow what you're doing sorry so it's best I back out.